Mispronouncing G-d's name "Adee-noy"
If a shaliach tzibur pronounces the name of G-d as "Adeenoy",

can one say "amen"?
Can one say "Boruch hu uvaruch shemo"?
Does one fulfil the requirement of tefila B'tzibur?
Can one read during Chazarat Hasha"tz?


That's one traditional Ashkenazi pronunciation of the name. What's the problem?

@Harel13, R' Shimon Schwab זצ"ל inveighs against the then-new mispronunciation of א–דִיני (yud added for emphasis) in R' Schwab on Prayer in one of the first maamarot (either Adon 'Olam or "Netilat yadayim")

Most of the people who make this pronunciation aren't aware that they're using a chirik, rather than a cholam, in my experience. FWIW, I'm voting to close as a request for psak

@NoachMiFrankfurt I tried an edit. Is that any better?

I prayed in a minyan Ashkenaz a few years where chazan on Yom Kippur was chassidic and said "barkheini" (bless me) instead of "barkheinu" etc. Nobody said a word and thanked him for a good job. Such is life. It's "tradition". It's one of the halakhos that one should require of oneself and accept another for whatever they do for the best of their ability. Overwhelming majority of people do not do Sefer Yetzira exercises and have accents regardless.

But that's different. That's the chassidic pronounciation. Adeenoy is correct according to no one. It's a cholam

@Chani chassidic is Burkhaini, not Barkheini

@YDJ not across the board, afaik

@Harel13 tell me more. Who pronounces a Cholam "ee"? (like cheese?)

This can be extended to those who pronounce It as “An-no” or “A-[nasal click]-noi”.

The variation in pronunciation is relying upon the very ancient tradition from Yaacov Avinu in Bereshit 32:31-32 with Peni'el and Penu'el, that the letter 'Vav' and the letter 'Yud' are interchangeable. This tradition is mentioned explicitly by Radak in his commentary as authoritative, legitimate and very old. In this case, the Cholam is exchanged with the Chirik. The intermediate stage between the two is Shirook.
